# how to remove progress dialog when tab orientation change in android

Tags: android

I've created two tabs with two different contents.one is video streaming another one has listview.

tab1->video streaming
tab2->listview.

Here i put progress dialog with text "Buffering video" for tab1 & progress dialog with text "loading" for listview.It works fine for portrait mode.while keeping on tab2,when i change its orientation into lanscape,it shows "loading.." & "buffering" both.How could i remove that "buffering" progress for tab2(landscape).?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to do some changes in your adapter in view portion like your all list item should be written like i did its working fine for me with portrait and landscape mode

```
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = ((LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.gallery_main_page_grid_item, parent, false);
            }
            Holder holder = new Holder();

            AQuery aq = listAQ.recycle(convertView);

            holder.imgView_Grid_Thumbnail_Gallery = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgView_Grid_Thumbnail_Gallery);

            if (holder.imgView_Grid_Thumbnail_Gallery != null) {
                aq.id(holder.imgView_Grid_Thumbnail_Gallery.getId()).image(dataArray.get(position).get("thumbUrl") + "/11");
            }

            holder.txtView_Grid_Name_Gallery = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_Grid_Name_Gallery);
            if (holder.txtView_Grid_Name_Gallery != null) {
                aq.id(holder.txtView_Grid_Name_Gallery.getId()).text(dataArray.get(position).get("user_name"));
                Typeface txtViewForName = Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/arial_bold.ttf");
                holder.txtView_Grid_Name_Gallery.setTypeface(txtViewForName);

            }
```

try to add your list item like this way.hope it will helpful.

if (convertView == null)
if (holder.txtView_Grid_Name_Gallery != null)

```
if (holder.imgView_GridItem_Gallery != null) {
    Bitmap cachedImage = aq.getCachedImage(R.drawable.loading);
    String publicUrl = dataArray.get(position).get("publicUrl") + "/13";
    if (aq.shouldDelay(convertView, parent, publicUrl, 0)) {
    aq.id(holder.imgView_GridItem_Gallery.getId()).image(cachedImage, 0.75f);
    } else {
    aq.id(holder.imgView_GridItem_Gallery.getId()).image(publicUrl, true, true, 0, 0, cachedImage, 0, 0.75f);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

should download android-query from android market and check the demo you will found all kind of demo from it regarding list view and gridview its so helpful

follow this steps:

(1)Go to google play
(2)download Android query app
(3)go in image loading option
(4)in that you will find list item there

there is your answer how list view works,you can also see source code from it its a best application with demo which are so useful

download this application :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidquery&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbmRyb2lkcXVlcnkiXQ

You can include jar files from this link

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list

download :android-query-full.0.22.10.jar for listview

Answer (score 0):

in onResume method you must check for ScreenOrientation.
For example first it comes as portrait, then in the if statement like following:
    if(orientation != portrait)
  {
       dismiss the dialog here....
  }

Try this...